# Simplify repeating Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a function where I'm changing the background position of a div 26 times at -250px. The function I have works but I'm sure it's done in the worst possible way and hope to simplify it.

```
$(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css('background-position', '-250px top');
    next();
});
```

I was curious if there is a way to change this so that I'm not repeating the same four lines 26 times with each chunk just having a -250px difference until it reaches -6500px.

Any insight it greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: per depperm's request, the full function:
Here's the full function. There can be X amount of items, each with a different background image and I'm using the same function for each.

```
$('.the-item').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-1000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-1250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-1500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-1750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-2000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-2250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-2500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-2750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-3000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-3250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-3500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-3750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-4000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-4250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-4500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-4750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-5000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-5250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-5500px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-5750px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-6000px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-6250px top');
        next();
    });
    $(this).delay( 25 ).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css('background-position', '-6500px top');
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add the rest of your relevant code?

Comment: if you need duration between the animation then use `setInterval()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat your 4 lines of code 26 times, then you can use a setTimeout and call a function that contains your 4 lines of code.

For example, something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var backPos = 0;
            function changeBackgroundPos(myDivId) {
                backPos -= 250;
                if (backPos > -6500) {
                    $('#'+myDivId).css('background-position', backPos.toString()+'px top');
                    $('#'+myDivId).html($('#'+myDivId).css('background-position'));
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        changeBackgroundPos(myDivId);
                    },1000);
                }
            }   
            changeBackgroundPos('myDiv');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #333;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```